# permission to bugzilla users & customize fields? but comments should not disable

Tags: perl, bug-tracking, bugzilla

I have some products

ProductA
ProductB

and groups in bugzilla.

Client
Developer

Only Developer should able the create/edit the fields but Client should not able to edit the bug.

The following discussion was very helpful for me.

[http://groups.google.com/group/netscape.public.mozilla.webtools/browse_thread/thread/98efcae88fe84d6d/51c8deb672402e09?lnk=gst&q=permissions+for+all+users#51c8deb672402e09](http://groups.google.com/group/netscape.public.mozilla.webtools/browse_thread/thread/98efcae88fe84d6d/51c8deb672402e09?lnk=gst&q=permissions%20for%20all%20users#51c8deb672402e09)

### Answer:

Product A:

ReadCreateA: Entry/Mandatory/Mandatory/--
EditA: --/NA/NA/Canedit
Similar for Product B.

For this, you need to give editbugs privileges to developers. If you want to restrict editbugs privileges in other products, you need to
set up a group they are *not* a member of as xx/xx/xx/Canedit for the other products. In your particular setup, this is already covered by
the EditA and EditB groups.

---

(Works fine )
When I use the above guide , it works perfectly except posting comments. I am getting following error while posting comment --> "You are not permitted to edit bugs in product Product A"

but I want users of "Group UsersA" should not edit the bug (that is fine) but must be able to post the comment.

What to do ?

Comment: I am thinking to change the code of bugzilla, I am using 3.6.3. But i don't know after submit the bug where this form will post and where i'll catch the request ? is it Bug.pl  file?



bug page url is http://localhost/show_bug.cgi?id=8 and after submitting it becomes http://localhost/process_bug.cgi with following Error msg "You are not permitted to edit bugs in product Product A". 



I am thinking to to catch the '<form>' request and write the if condition for following text area. 



'<textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>'
is it possible ?